# Prove there is a matching of size n/2 on a graph with 2n vertices each of degree n

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, matching

Given underirected $n$-regular graph with $2n$ nodes, I am asked to show it has a matching of size $n/2$.

My attempt:

At each step I will also remove the edge from the graph that I am adding to the matching $M$ edges.

I start at random edge $(u,v)$ and add it to $M$. The degree of nodes $u$ and $v$ is now decreased. I am going to keep removing random edges $(u,v)$ such that before removing them both $u$ and $v$ have a degree $n$.

I will prove that I will never fail. Assume that after some step $i<n/2$ there are no 2 nodes which both have degree $n$. However, this implies that there are only at most $2i+1$ nodes of degree $n$ in the initial graph, which is a contradiction.

My question is, whether suggesting a procedure is a valid proof to solve such problems?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Giving an algorithm is not enough, you must prove its correctness. Here your proof of correctness is not correct: you would need to assume that there are no two *adjacent* nodes, both with degree $n$.